# Can Corda CRaSH Shell handle UniqueIdentifier fow parameter value?

Tags: corda

When trying to start a flow via the secondary constructor
flow start ProposeFlow$Sender info: { recipientBank: "CN=Bank A,O=Bank A,L=Amsterdam,C=NL", amount: $10, paymentInstruction: "abc", toCurrency: USD, isFXConversionBySenderBank: true, linearId: e8a8c979-c889-433e-b102-fe43fdae7e1a }

I got
No matching constructor found:
- [recipientBank: Party, amount: Amount, paymentInstruction: String, toCurrency: Currency, isFXConversionBySenderBank: boolean, linearId: UniqueIdentifier]: missing parameter recipientBank
- [Info]: Could not parse as a command: Can not construct instance of net.corda.core.contracts.UniqueIdentifier: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('e8a8c979-c889-433e-b102-fe43fdae7e1a')
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: argent.flow.ProposeFlow$Info["linearId"])
- [Party, Amount, String, Currency, boolean, UniqueIdentifier, int, DefaultConstructorMarker]:

Via the primary constructor,
flow start ProposeFlow$Sender recipientBank: "CN=Bank A,O=Bank A,L=Amsterdam,C=NL", amount: $10, paymentInstruction: "abc", toCurrency: USD, isFXConversionBySenderBank: true, linearId: e8a8c979-c889-433e-b102-fe43fdae7e1a

I got
No matching constructor found:
- [Party, Amount, String, Currency, boolean, UniqueIdentifier]: Could not parse as a command: Can not construct instance of net.corda.core.contracts.UniqueIdentifier: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('e8a8c979-c889-433e-b102-fe43fdae7e1a')
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
- [info: Info]: too many parameters
- [Party, Amount, String, Currency, boolean, UniqueIdentifier, int, DefaultConstructorMarker]:

Here are the flow constructors -
object ProposeFlow {
    @CordaSerializable
    data class Info (val recipientBank: Party,
                     val amount: Amount,
                     val paymentInstruction: String,
                     val toCurrency: Currency = amount.token,
                     val isFXConversionBySenderBank: Boolean = true,
                     val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier())

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class Sender(val recipientBank: Party,
             val amount: Amount<Currency>,
             val paymentInstruction: String,
             val toCurrency: Currency = amount.token,
             val isFXConversionBySenderBank: Boolean = true,
             val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    constructor(info: Info): this (
            recipientBank = info.recipientBank,
            amount = info.amount,
            paymentInstruction = info.paymentInstruction,
            toCurrency = info.toCurrency,
            isFXConversionBySenderBank = info.isFXConversionBySenderBank,
            linearId = info.linearId
    )
```

Is there a way around?

Thanks.

\Sean

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug (missing feature) - the shell should support UUID parsing. It's an easy fix if you'd like to submit a PR: look here:

https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/shell/InteractiveShell.kt#L184

You'd just need to add a Yaml deserialiser for UniqueIdentifier which is probably two or three lines of code.

I've filed it here: https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/1123